# How can I create filters with radio buttons in yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm new to Yii framework. Now in the admin page, I get the gridview of the data. I have a column named approved in the gridview which has either 0 or 1 as its value. I now want to introduce two radio buttons 0 and 1 which filters the results with 0 and 1 respectively and displays it.
 How can I create filters with radio buttons

Answer (score 1):

You can make your filter into pretty much anything:

```
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'name' => 'approved',
         'filter' => CHtml::radioButton(...) . CHtml::radioButton(...),
    ),
),
```

But if you want to keep things simple, just feed an array into the filter.

```
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'name' => 'approved',
        'filter' => ['0','1'],
    ),
),
```

It will generate a dropdown-list (sorry, no automatic radiobuttons) but it's very functional I swear!

If you want text options provide them like this:

```
'filter' => ['1'=>'On', '0'=>'Off'],
```

Also, Yii will automatically generate a filter for you if you set the type to boolean

```
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'name' => 'approved',
        'type' => 'boolean'
    ),
)
```

And finally there is even a shortcut for setting the type:

```
'columns'=>array(
    'approved:boolean',
)
```

*I know, too many dropdowns and too few radiobuttons. Sorry.*

Answer (score 1):

For radio buttons, amend your **_search.php** like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'isPublished'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'isPublished', 
        array('1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No')
    ); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'isPublished'); ?>
</div>
```

Make sure your model's search function already has this to work:

```
$criteria->compare('isPublished', $this->isPublished);
```

Also, make sure this attribute is defined as **safe** in the model rules.